# ASP.NET MVC Razor: how to add a Css style class or ID on the link below

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

`@Html.ActionLink("Some link text", "MyAction", "MyController", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: "MyAnchor", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: null)`

Current output:
`<a href="/#MyAnchor"> Some Link Text</a>`

I want it to be :
`<a class="smoothScroll" href="/#MyAnchor">Some Link Text</a>`

If they is a better way to do this in ASP.NET MVC +4 Razor, please assist. Thanks

Comment: That's at least one of the thing you use the `htmlAttributes` parameter for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the html attributes for html helpers in ASP.NET MVC3 C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510877/what-are-the-html-attributes-for-html-helpers-in-asp-net-mvc3-c)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the following as the htmlAttributes parameter:

```
new { @class = "smoothScroll" }
```

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Some link text", "MyAction", "MyController", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: "MyAnchor", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes:new { @class = "smoothScroll" }) :I have tried this code above

Comment: And the one below but the brower gives me an error that the page cant be run error  new { @class  =  "smoothScroll" }

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Some link text", "MyAction", "MyController", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: "MyAnchor", routeValues: null, new { @class  =  "smoothScroll" }).

Comment: @PaulT.@TiesonT